# What is wrong with my regexp {2,3}

Tags: java, regex

I got a regexp to validate an email address like this `^[\\w\\d_\\.]+@[[a-z]+\\.]*[a-z]{2,3}$`

The last part **`{2,3}`** means that there have to be 2 or 3 characters at the end of the input string. But for an input shown below it returns true.

```
    String input = "person.name@domain.gov.ukzzz";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\w\\d_\\.]+@[[a-z]+\\.]*[a-z]{2,3}$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(input + " --> " + matcher.matches());
```

output is `person.name@domain.gov.ukzzz --> true`

**Why?**

Comment: For starters: `[[a-z]+\\.]*` is invalid (character classes do not nest.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `[[a-z]+\\.]*` matches `domain.gov.ukz` in your case, that's why. It will also match `+++` by the way, which is illegal.

Try this instead:

```
"^[\\w\\d_\\.]+@([a-z]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,3}$"
```

HOWEVER: real email addresses are much more complex than this regex; I suggest you use the javamail API and its `InternetAddress` instead: it will parse for you, without errors. For one, in your regex, you fail to account for the fact that digits are *legal* within a hostname. `foo@4.pm` is a *valid* email address.

Comment: +1, e-mail addresses can be really weird...  http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/

Answer (score 1):

This is because there *are* 2-3 `a-z` characters at the end of the string: `zz` and `zzz` both satisfy it.  The `[[a-z]+\\.]*` is not required (and should probably be in parentheses anyway).  I thought you want it to be something like:

```
([a-z]*\\.)
```

The `.` should probably be required.